# JNI function not getting invoked

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I need to debug JNI issue of a team member. The problem is in a Java app interfacing a USB connected hardware using JNI. He mentions that JNI functions implemented in a C++ dll are not getting called by Java app. Also he specifically mentioned that it is a not an unsatisified link error problem, which was the first thing I would suspect.

The strange thing is that the Java App works fine on his development system and the JNI calls are being made properly. However on the target machine of the QA team, the Java app does not seem to work.

The DLL (32-bit) was generated using VS2010 and the target machine was WinXP/Win 7 32-bit system. I would rule out DLL method signature issue since DLL was recognised on the development system. As mentioned, it was not link issue.

What could be the issue in JNI methods not getting invoked at all? Could this be a problem with redistributables? How to debug (using JVM options) and ascertain the problem?

Comment: What do you mean 'does not get called'?

Comment: Assuming the DLL is statically linked to the CRT, do you have the correct CRT redist installed on the target machine?

Comment: The app has a control to init the hardware and the JNI init() is supposed to be called. It was observed that hardware did not get initialized so guessing init() was not called. How to confirm this?

Comment: Is it sufficient to check for VC 10.0 redist in control panel? Thanks.

Comment: @Mano : No, as there are multiple versions of the CRT redist -- you need the version corresponding to the exact version of VC++ that the C++ dll was built with. [Time to start reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx)... ;-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard debugging procedure:

1. set breakpoint in Java
2. run to breakpoint
3. attach debugger to java executable (visual studio attach by process ID)
4. set breakpoint in JNI.
5. continue Java program.

Comment: This could be an option on dev system but on the remote QA system I dont have VS. Is there any possibility to trace the JNI calls using JVN commandline options?

Comment: No. Java makes about a bazillion of its own JNI calls, so java -verbose:jni isn't a call-level trace. It still might tell you something.